# Add row to data frame with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this sample data:

```
cvar <- c("2015-11-01","2015-11-02","All")
nvar1 <- c(12,10,5)
nvar2 <- c(7,5,6)
data <- cbind.data.frame(cvar,nvar1,nvar2)
```

And I just want to add a new row to the data.frame containing the sums of nvar1 & nvar2 and a character, so with base R I would just use

```
data[nrow(data)+1,] <- c("add",sum(data[,2]),sum(data[,3]))
```

or something more clever with lapply, but just to show you what I'm looking for.

I would like this simple command within the pipe environment, so data %>% ... gives me the above outcome.

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You have any `data.table` here.

Comment: as soon as you give it into the pipe it will become a data.table, doesnt it?

Comment: `data.table` is a different package.  TO convert to `data.table`, it should be `data.table(cvar, ....)`  If you are using `dplyr`, then try with `bindrows`

Comment: You may be referring to `tbl_df`

Comment: Ah okay, I'm sorry will edit this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this then maybe:

```
data %>% 
     rbind(c("add",sum(nvar1),sum(nvar2)))
#        cvar nvar1 nvar2
#1 2015-11-01    12     7
#2 2015-11-02    10     5
#3        All     5     6
#4        add    27    18
```

Edit:

According to your comment, this will work:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(nvar3 = nvar1) %>% 
  rbind(c("add",sum(nvar1),sum(nvar2),sum(.$nvar3)))
```

Using the `.` will allow `rbind` to find `nvar3`

Edit2:

Provide the new row as a list and it will maintain the column classes:

```
> str(
+ data %>% 
+   mutate(nvar3 = nvar1) %>% 
+   rbind(list("add",sum(nvar1),sum(nvar2),sum(.$nvar3))) 
+ )
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ cvar : chr  "2015-11-01" "2015-11-02" "All" "add"
 $ nvar1: num  12 10 5 27
 $ nvar2: num  7 5 6 18
 $ nvar3: num  12 10 5 27
```

Comment: The only way I can justify "dplyr" here is if you include the conversion of the first column to "character". `data %>% mutate(cvar = as.character(cvar)) %>% rbind(c("add",sum(nvar1),sum(nvar2)))`. Otherwise, `rbind(data, c("add",sum(nvar1),sum(nvar2)))` would also do the same....

Comment: Thank you LyzandeR, that does solve the problem stated above, +1. But inside a pipe it doesn't work for me say: data %>% mutate(nvar3 = nvar1) %>% rbind(c("add",sum(nvar1),sum(nvar2),sum(nvar3))) , I need to use the rbind after a long series of transformations, did not mention this in the question sorry for that..

Comment: @Sebastian Yeah in the case you describe above `nvar3` cannot be found in `data` and hence the error. You should do it like this: `data %>% 
  mutate(nvar3 = nvar1) %>% 
  rbind(c("add",sum(nvar1),sum(nvar2),sum(.$nvar3)))` and it will work.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I totally agree. It seems that the OP needed it as a step in a more complex situation.

Comment: By rbinding a character vector, you've converted the nvars to char in the result.

Comment: @Frank Yeah that's true. Probably the OP did not mind about this as he got the same result using `[` in his question.

Comment: I did mutate_each(as.numeric,...) in the next step, is there a better way to keep the class in the first place? For my case it's no problem as I only have a few hundred rows at this stage of my code, but for other cases this might be useful.

Answer (score 48):

With `tibble` version 1.2 you can use `add_row()`

https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/29/tibble-1-2-0/

```
data %>% 
 add_row(cvar = "add", nvar1 = sum(nvar1), nvar2 = sum(nvar2))
```

Comment: this is working because the vectors are defined in the global environment. Would be nice to have a lazy eval of the column names. Opened an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/200)

Comment: This is now working fine with lazy eval of column names, clearly the most `tidyverse` option imo!

Answer (score 14):

Using only `dplyr` you could do the following

```
data %<>%
  summarise(cvar = "add",
            nvar1 = sum(nvar1),
            nvar2 = sum(nvar2)) %>%
  bind_rows(data)
```

which results in

```
        cvar nvar1 nvar2
1        add    27    18
2 2015-11-01    12     7
3 2015-11-02    10     5
4        All     5     6
```

Note that this way the new row is added **at the beginning** rather than the end of the original dataframe.

If you want to add the new row **at the end instead**, use the following code (thanks to [krlmlr for pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565949/add-row-to-data-frame-with-dplyr/40755692#comment69034451_40755692))

```
data %<>%
  summarise(cvar = "add",
            nvar1 = sum(nvar1),
            nvar2 = sum(nvar2)) %>%
  bind_rows(data, .)
```

which results in

```
        cvar nvar1 nvar2
1 2015-11-01    12     7
2 2015-11-02    10     5
3        All     5     6
4        add    27    18
```

Comment: Use `bind_rows(data, .)` to add to the end.

Comment: @krlmlr Thanks! I didn't realize it's that easy to add the new row at the end. Funily the warning message `In bind_rows_(x, .id) : binding factor and character vector, coercing into character vector` appears while doing this – but it doesn't appear the other way round (`bind_rows(., data)`). Do you know why that is?

Comment: Simpler example: `bind_rows(data_frame(a = "a"), data_frame(a = factor("a")))` vs. `bind_rows(data_frame(a = factor("a")), data_frame(a = "a"))` . Seems to depend on the order, perhaps the absence of a warning in my first example is a simple omission. Double-check the [dplyr NEWS](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that it depends on the order... but to me this behaviour seems inconsistent so I've [opened a corresponding issue on GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2317) :)

Answer (score 6):

One option utilizing `summarise_all()` and `bind_rows()` could be:

```
data %>% 
 bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~ if (is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "add"))

        cvar nvar1 nvar2
1 2015-11-01    12     7
2 2015-11-02    10     5
3        All     5     6
4        add    27    18
```

Or adding the row and then calculating the sum only for that last row using `if_else()`:

```
data %>%
 add_row(cvar = "add") %>%
 mutate_at(-1, ~ if_else(row_number() == max(row_number()), sum(., na.rm = TRUE), .))
```

Or an alternative to @Rickard's answer when the variables are not in global environment:

```
data %>% 
 add_row(cvar = "add", nvar1 = sum(data$nvar1), nvar2 = sum(data$nvar2))
```

Comment: Top ! Thanks
Would add to use sum(., na.rm = T)

Comment: Would also add to use brackets to prevent warnings in RStudio:
data %>% 
 bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~ if (is.numeric(.)) {sum(., na.rm = T)} else {"Total"}))

Comment: Using the summarise_all() and bind_rows() options shown above, how to add a row conditionally? For example, add one row (e.g., cvar="Others") if the sum (nvar1+nvar2)<15 and remove all individual rows where (nvar1+nvar2)<15?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for an universal solution I would be use:

```
cvar <- c("2015-11-01","2015-11-02","All")
nvar1 <- c(12,10,5)
nvar2 <- c(7,5,6)
data <- tibble::tibble(cvar,nvar1,nvar2)

purrr::map_df(data, ~c(.x, ifelse(is.numeric(.x), sum(.x, na.rm=TRUE), NA)))
```

P.S. I use tibble to keep character because a data frame converts them to factor and base::c "destroy" them